# Stylish: How to import styles?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, import, styles

This query is about the [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) addon for Firefox. How do I import my Stylish styles on one account/computer to another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end, I just copied over the file where Stylish stores its styles. This is a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) file (`stylish.sqlite`) typically located in:

- **Windows Vista/Windows 7**: `C:\Users\Your-Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Some-Random-String.default`
- **Windows XP**: `C:\Documents and Settings\Your-Username\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Some-Random-String.default`

Answer (score 1):

Copy/paste works well for me, I just email the style info to home/work as required.

Another way would be to create an account on [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/help/userstylesorg#post) and upload them there to make them available where you, and indeed anyone else, might be.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a small amount of styles, you could copypaste the existing files into several text files. Low-tech, but it'd do. <s>For larger amounts, well, I'll get back to you on that one.</s>

Well, a quick search using Everything (pointing it towards my ff profile, searching for .css), didn't turn up anything relevant, so I assume they're in some database. It's in there, though, you could just copy your profile. (`%AppData%\Local\Roaming\Mozilla`, here)